# Speeding Up Arithmetic Operation in C++

Tags: c++, math

I have a loop that is consistently running this operation and according to measurements this function is about 40% of my total program runtime. Are there any techniques I can apply to speed up this code?

```
inline bool calculate(int64_t num1, double num2, int64_t num3, double num4) {
    return (num1 * num2) < (num3 + num4);
}
```

Comment: I'd 1st try to compile the whole code using varying optimization levels, and thoroughly measure, before starting to try micro optimizations at that level. And if I am sure about that's the bottleneck, I'd do some analysis of the generated machine code, and if I could do something better by hand.

Comment: You might try using const reference. Note that the function will be in-lined effectively only if the function is in the same .cpp file as the caller, or in a .h.